# Java 8 streams - use original streamed object along the stream action

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am running `Stream` operations on an array of `Integer`s.
I then create a `Cell` object that does some manipulations and apply a filter,
and I want to create a map of `Integer` to `Cell` with only the valid `Cell`s.

Something along this line:

```
List<Integer> type = new ArrayList<>();

Map<Integer, Cell> map =
  list.stream()
    .map(x -> new Cell(x+1, x+2))        // Some kind of Manipulations
    .filter(cell->isNewCellValid(cell))  // filter some
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(....));
```

Is it possible to use original streamed object along the stream action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the original `Stream` element if your `map` operation creates some instance that contains it.

For example:

```
Map<Integer, Cell> map =
  list.stream()
      .map(x -> new SomeContainerClass(x,new Cell(x+1, x+2)))
      .filter(container->isNewCellValid(container.getCell()))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(c->c.getIndex(),c->c.getCell()));
```

There are some existing classes you can use instead of creating your own `SomeContainerClass`, such as `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`:

```
Map<Integer, Cell> map =
  list.stream()
      .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,Cell>(x,new Cell(x+1, x+2)))
      .filter(e->isNewCellValid(e.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: I've always wondered if that pattern goes against the preferred statelessness of stream operations. But I guess it's fine...

Comment: @daniu I'm not sure what you mean by that. Is there anything stateful in my suggested solution? You have to keep in the elements of the Stream all the data which is required to produce the required output.

Comment: No you're right, the way you posted it it's no problem. I was thinking about a `ContainerClass` that is created before the creation of the stream and is then fed the stream's elements, so it does change it's state during processing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use original streamed object along the stream action?

Yes, until you don't use a `map` operation.

You need a `Function<Cell, Integer>` to restore an original value. In your example, it is `(Cell cell) -> cell.getFirst() - 1`:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(cell -> cell.getFirst() - 1, Function.identity()));
```

I suggest writing `Function<Integer, Cell>` and `Function<Cell, Integer>` functions and not building unnecessary wrapper classes for a single stream process:

```
final Function<Integer, Cell> xToCell = x -> new Cell(x + 1, x + 2);
final Function<Cell, Integer> cellToX = cell -> cell.getX1() - 1;

final Map<Integer, Cell> map =
        list
                .stream()
                .map(xToCell)
                .filter(cell -> isNewCellValid(cell))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(cellToX, Function.identity()));
```

Of course, it's efficient for the operations that can be simply or intuitively inverted.